# how to fix react-app-rewired freeze when save?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-app-rewired

When I edit something on development my app will freeze until I refresh it.

However, I try to use `FAST_REFRESH=false` in script start it refresh app.

But, in another framework like `vite js` or just pure react it just update content, and not refresh I want like that.

This is my script :

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "FAST_REFRESH=false react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired --env=jsdom",
    "less": "lessc --js src/styles/wieldy.less public/css/style.css && lessc --js src/styles/wieldy.less public/css/style.min.css --compress -x"
  },
```

Comment: Which `another framework`? Please specify this in the question itself.

Comment: like vite or normal react